# Updating a numeric Key/Value pair in an Array of Object State is returning NaN Error in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm working on an eCommerce Project and in the Cart Page of my ReactJS Project, I want to add an increment and decrement function, but adding the increment function is returning a NaN error.

```
  function handleIncrement(pID){
    setCartData(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === pID) {
          return {...obj, Amount: Amount + 1};
        }

        return obj;
      });

      return newState;
    });
  }
```

this is the Increment Function, it's taking an id on clicking the increment button on the page which checks the cartData State for a matching id of object and adds 1 to the Amount and returns the state.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eb2auu?file=src%2FWebpages%2FCart.js,src%2FWebpages%2FProductDetail.js

Here is the full code and hosted version for the webpage/site ^

I've tried setting the original state to the newstate, using .find() and making two different states but it's resulting in the same error. It doesn't update the value in the amount box on the page and just returns an NaN error.

Comment: are you sure Amount gives you a value?, maybe you have to access to some props of the element to get number value

Comment: Maybe the initial value of `Amount` is not set to `0` and it is doing `undefined + 1` and returning `NaN`

Comment: Should it be `Amount: obj.Amount + 1`?

Comment: `Amount: obj.Amount + 1` worked, thanks Steven.